Function for frame affine transformations in libav (ffmpeg)?
I need to perform affine transformation to AVFrame data (mostly dxva2 NV12).
I found no procedure or options in frame or hwcontext.
Looked into filters - and nothing (google found av_filter_transform, but I'm not found it in any build includes).
Is there any option to do this such a basic operation? May be I missed some DXVA option? Or at least filters (although using such a beast...).
